# Weird behavior in plotting pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas series like so:

```
print(df)
date
2010-01-01    16.9
2010-04-01    16.7
2010-07-01    15.9
2010-10-01    15.8
2011-01-01    16.4
2011-04-01    15.4
2011-07-01    14.7
2011-10-01    15.1
2012-01-01    14.7
2012-04-01    14.5
2012-07-01    15.3
              ...
2014-04-01    10.7
2014-07-01    10.4
2014-10-01    10.0
2015-01-01    10.3
2015-04-01    10.1
2015-07-01    10.8
2015-10-01    10.7
2016-01-01    11.0
2016-04-01    10.4
2016-07-01    10.0
2016-10-01     9.0
```

I am trying to plot it using `matplotlib` like so:

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

But somehow the plot is coming with weird vertical lines like so:
[image]

Why is that? And how can I fix it?

I am running this in jupyter lab if that helps.

Comment: The plot did not come from the same data you've shown (the value in `2010-01-01` did not match the location on the plot). Are you sure that your data is not corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

We could better help if you would give us what you have. I wanted to make a comment, but I can do my job better in an answer.

So I've created a text file from the data what you presented.

```
data.csv
========
date;val
2010-01-01;16.9
2010-04-01;16.7
2010-07-01;15.9
2010-10-01;15.8
2011-01-01;16.4
2011-04-01;15.4
2011-07-01;14.7
2011-10-01;15.1
2012-01-01;14.7
2012-04-01;14.5
2012-07-01;15.3
2014-04-01;10.7
2014-07-01;10.4
2014-10-01;10.0
2015-01-01;10.3
2015-04-01;10.1
2015-07-01;10.8
2015-10-01;10.7
2016-01-01;11.0
2016-04-01;10.4
2016-07-01;10.0
2016-10-01;9.0
```

Then I've read it into pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",
                 delimiter=";",
                 parse_dates=['date'],
                 index_col='date')
```

Then I've done the plot like you:

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

and got a completely different result (that's why we would need to now what exactly you have tried):

[image: pandas plot]